# Problems connecting to an sql database using Powershell & MySql Connector

Tags: mysql, sql, powershell

about a year ago i came across @FoxDeploy explaining how to connect to an `sql` database using `MySql Connector` the explanation was second to none and helped no end,fast forward a year we have a new server and i cant for the life of me figure out why the `Invoke-MySqlQuery` is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet when everything has been installed and pointing to the `dll`

please see script below

```
$MySQLConnection = $null
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files (x86)\MySql\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.28\Assemblies\v4.5.2\MySql.Data.dll")
$MySQLConnection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$MySQLConnection.ConnectionString = “server=*******;port=****;user id=********;password=***********;database=************;pooling=false”
$MySQLConnection.Open()

#Define our column headings (needed for the Insert statement)
$columns="meta_id,post_id,meta_key,meta_value"

#import our csv
$csv = import-csv "C:\Users\TEMP.redec.004\Desktop\TEST\*.csv" 

 
 ForEach ($record in $csv){
    $query = "REPLACE INTO wp_postmeta ($columns) VALUES ('$($record.meta_id)',`
             '$($record.post_id)','$($record.meta_key)','$($record.meta_value)');"
             

Invoke-MySqlQuery  Query $query -Verbose 
 start-sleep -Milliseconds 5

}
```

this is the correct path leading to the dll
`("C:\Program Files (x86)\MySql\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.28\Assemblies\v4.5.2\MySql.Data.dll")`

Comment: Where is `Invoke-MySqlQuery` defined? Certainly not in that referenced .NET assembly. Any PowerShell cmdlet will be likely just a wrapper around that DLL, e. g. [this one](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Invoke-MySqlQuery/1.0.0/Content/Invoke-MySqlQuery.ps1).

Comment: @zett42 forgive me but i am not to sure what you mean, normally i install the connector and in the `Powershell` script point the  `[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom`  to the path where `MySql.Data.dll` is, this has always worked and the cmdlet is recognized

Comment: You seem to have a misconception that loading "MySql.Data.dll" is all you need to query MySQL from PowerShell. In addition you have to install one of the [PowerShell MySQL modules](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages?q=Tags%3A%22mysql%22).

Comment: On the old server (the one that works) CommandType = Function Name | = Invoke-MySqlQuery | Version = 1.0 |Source = MySQL, On the new server  The term 'Invoke-MySqlQuery' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: @zett42 you are right, I remember now I installed one of these modules thank you buddy 